# How to decrease actionbar tabs width programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

How to manage the action bar tabs width.here attaching [image: screen .]

Comment: Here i ahave another tab also ,i want to adjust other tab also with out scrolling the tabs

Comment: Is that because your images don't fill the whole tabs? Shouldn't you just try to prepare better images?

Comment: @Szymon, I guess the OP is trying to say that they do not want the scrolling in tab titles. They want all titles visible in one screen, i.e., if there are total 5 tabs, all titles should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing their default padding, by overriding the default style:

```
<style name="TabViewNoPadding" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

And then set this style in your app theme:

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/TabViewNoPadding</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Action Bar Tab style.

For Android version less than 14, add the following to your application theme;

```
<style name="Theme.Apptheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Apptheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Apptheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

For version 14 and onwards, refer the same.

```
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Apptheme</item>
```